# Is there a construct or pattern similar to C# `using` which will return an object?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF message inspector which inspects requests and responses: `Message`. The inspector works fine. A `Message` object can only be read once so once you read it, you cannot simply propagate as WCF will complain that the message has been read. Therefore, I am creating a brand new copy of the message and propagating that.

I have designed a class that allows message reading and after the caller has read whatever they want, they need to call `Close` which will return a copy of the message. Here is the skeleton of my class:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

internal abstract class MessageReader 
{
    internal string ReadSomething(string id)
    {
        // Return string
    }

    internal string ReadSomethingElse(string id)
    {
        // Return string
    }

    internal Message Close()
    {
        // Create copy and return it. 
    }
}
```

Users of my class may forget to call `Close()` which is fine because WCF will yell at them. Right now I have documentation to let users know they need to call `Close()`.

**Here is the question**

Is there a pattern, or something similar, to C#'s `using` construct but one which returns an object at the end? This will be really convenient because then users of my class can just use a construct like that and at the end it will return the copy of the message. Something like this:

```
UsingSomeConstruct(var reader = new MessageReader(ref originalMessage))
{
     var a = reader.ReadSomething("something");
     var b = reader.ReadSomethingElse("something");

     // Do something with what was read
}

// At this point originalMessage will be the copy of the message and no longer the original message.
```

**EDIT**

I thought about hacking `IDisposable` to achieve this but I am NOT going to do it that way so looking for other ideas.

Comment: Instead of requiring to call `Close` to return a copy of the message, why don't you make your `MessageReader` create a copy of the message the first time read is requested and operate on the copy? i.e. copy on read, propagate the original.

Comment: @IvanStoev I think you can't create copy without reading original - so you'll endup needing 2 copies...

Comment: Since you can't use that `ref` parameter the way you want you'd have to use delegates - which makes code looking quite insane... oterwise just implementing IDisposable on your `MessageReader` will achieve what you want...

Comment: I see. So I guess you are maintaining internally a `MessageBuffer` that you need to dispose at the end. Then you can make the `MessageReader` disposable and add `ref message` argument to each `Read` method.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes I thought about doing the IDisposable hack and instead of disposing setting `ref originalMessage` to the copy. But I thought I might get kicked in the you know what by other devs

Comment: @IvanStoev operating on the copy is fine, but the caller will still have the original

Comment: I meant to replace it inside the `Read` calls (basically the first call).

Comment: But the caller will need the copy. So eventually they will need to call Close()

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you are right. Creating a copy requires reading.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no such construct. It is simply too specific to exist there out of the box. There are extension methods which often are very helpful, but you won't be able to use them on `this ref Message` parameter..

However, if you are willing to use `ref` at all, then why dont simply include all that logic it in Reader's constructor?

Here's an example, somewhat contrived, but it should show what I mean. Like others mentioned in comments, I also suggest implementing IDisposable on the Reader object instead of Close, so I included that already.

TL;DR: In example below, the most important thing is in Reader(ref msg) constructor which clones the message, copies the data, and replaces the original message with a safe-message class which can be read many times..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // real-world variables, keep them typed as base Message
            // to be able to silently replace them with different objects
            Message original1;
            Message original2;

            // let's construct some one-time readable messages
            {
                var tmp1 = new OneTimeMessage();
                tmp1.data["mom"] = "dad";
                tmp1.data["cat"] = "dog";
                original1 = tmp1;

                var tmp2 = new OneTimeMessage();
                tmp2.data["mom"] = "dad";
                tmp2.data["cat"] = "dog";
                original2 = tmp2;
            }


            // test1 - can't read twice

            Console.WriteLine("test0A:" + original1.GetData("mom"));
            //Console.WriteLine("test0B:" + original1.GetData("mom")); // fail


            // test2 - can read twice with Reader's help

            var backup1 = original2;
            using(var rd1 = new Reader(ref original2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test1A:" + rd1.ReadSomething("mom"));
            }

            var backup2 = original2;
            using(var rd2 = new Reader(ref original2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test1A:" + rd2.ReadSomething("mom"));
                //^ ok - becase Reader replaced 'original2' with SafeMessage
            }


            // test3: Reader's ctor is intelligent
            // so no more SafeMessages created during future usage
            var backup3 = original2;
            using(var rd3 = new Reader(ref original2))
            {
            }

            var backup4 = original2;
            using(var rd4 = new Reader(ref original2))
            {
            }

            Console.WriteLine("checking for copies:" + (original2 == backup1));
            Console.WriteLine("checking for copies:" + (original2 == backup2));
            Console.WriteLine("checking for copies:" + (original2 == backup3));
            Console.WriteLine("checking for copies:" + (original2 == backup4));
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Message
{
    public abstract string GetData(string id);
}

public class OneTimeMessage : Message // this models your current one-time-readable message
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public override string GetData(string id)
    {
        var tmp = data[id];
        data.Remove(id);
        // that's nonsense, but I want to show that you can't
        // read the same thing twice from this object
        return tmp;
    }
}

public class SafeMessage : Message
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> data;

    public override String GetData(string id)
    {
        return data[id];
    }

    public SafeMessage(Message msg)
    {
        // read out the full msg's data and store it
        // since this is example, we can do it in a pretty simple way
        // in your code that will probably be more complex
        this.data = new Dictionary<string,string>(((OneTimeMessage)msg).data);
    }
}

public class Reader : IDisposable
{
    private Message message;
    public Reader(ref Message src)
    {
        src = src is SafeMessage ? src : new SafeMessage(src);
        this.message = src;
    }

    public string ReadSomething(string id){ return message.GetData(id); }
    public void Dispose(){ Close(); }
    public void Close(){ message=null; Console.WriteLine("reader closed"); }
}
```

EDIT: improved example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // real-world variables, keep them typed as base Message
            // to be able to silently replace them with different objects
            Message original1;
            Message original2;

            // let's construct some one-time readable messages
            {
                original1 = new TheMessage("dad", "dog");
                original2 = new TheMessage("dad", "dog");
            }


            // test1 - can't read twice

            Console.WriteLine("test0A:" + original1.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml());
            // Console.WriteLine("test0B:" + original1.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml()); // fail: InvalidOperationException - it was already read


            // test2 - can read ONCE with Reader's help, but the message is replaced and is usable again

            var backup1 = original2;
            using (var rd1 = new ReaderOnce(ref original2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("is message replaced after opening Reader:" + (original2 != backup1));

                Console.WriteLine("test1A:" + rd1.ReadBodyXml());
                // Console.WriteLine("test1B:" + rd1.ReadBodyXml()); // fail: InvalidOperationException - it was already read
            }


            // test3 - can read MANY TIMES with ReaderMany's help
            // also note we use 'original2' again, which was already used above, so in fact ReaderOnce really works as well

            var backup2 = original2;
            using (var rd1 = new ReaderMany(ref original2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("is message replaced after opening Reader:" + (original2 != backup2));

                Console.WriteLine("test2A:" + rd1.ReadBodyXml());
                Console.WriteLine("test2B:" + rd1.ReadBodyXml()); // ok
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

// solution1
public class ReaderOnce : IDisposable
{
    private Message localCopy;

    public ReaderOnce(ref Message src)
    {
        // create a WCF MessageBuffer to assist in copying messages
        // btw. I suppose you should set some sane limit instead of that below
        using (var tempBuffer = src.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue))
        {
            src = tempBuffer.CreateMessage(); // FIRST copy for outer use
            localCopy = tempBuffer.CreateMessage(); // SECOND copy for internal use in the Reader
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { Close(); }

    public void Close()
    {
        localCopy.Close(); // but that does NOT affect FIRST copy sent to outer scope outside reader
        Console.WriteLine("reader closed");
    }

    public string ReadBodyXml() // careful: that's again ONE TIME readable
    {
        return localCopy.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml();
    }
}

// solution2
public class ReaderMany : IDisposable
{
    private MessageBuffer localBuffer;

    public ReaderMany(ref Message src)
    {
        localBuffer = src.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        src = localBuffer.CreateMessage(); // FIRST copy for outer use
    }

    public void Dispose() { Close(); }

    public void Close()
    {
        localBuffer.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("reader closed");
    }

    public string ReadBodyXml() // this is readable multiple times
    {
        using (var tmp = localBuffer.CreateMessage())
            return tmp.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml();
    }
}


// let's fake some Message type to have something to test the Reader on
public class TheMessage : Message
{
    public override MessageHeaders Headers => _mh;

    public override MessageProperties Properties => _mp;

    public override MessageVersion Version => _mv;

    private MessageHeaders _mh;
    private MessageProperties _mp;
    private MessageVersion _mv;

    private string data1;
    private string data2;

    // btw. below: surprise! XmlDictionaryWriter is in "System.Runtime.Serialization", not in "System.Xml"
    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("foo");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("data1", data1);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("data2", data2);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public TheMessage(string data1, string data2)
    {
        // remember, this class is just an example, you will work on your own messages you already have
        _mv = MessageVersion.Soap12;
        _mh = new MessageHeaders(_mv);
        _mp = new MessageProperties();

        // below: yeah, that's super-naive and wrong, but that's an example
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry IDisposable will not do. I thought about this before I posted the question. See comments to my question please.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Read my code carefully to see that IDisposable is irrelevant. The important thing is in Reader(ref msg) constructor which clones the message, copies the data, and replaces the original message with a safe-message class which can be read many times..

Comment: @CodingYoshi: btw. I did not hack IDisposable and using.. I only used it to properly handle Reader's Closeing so users will not forget :) ... well unless they forget to use using :):)

Comment: which reader's closing? In `Dispose` your are calling `Close()` which sets message to null. If you set the message to null what would the caller have at the end? Give me a few mins to give this a try.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: so.. did you try it out? FYI: setting `null` in `Close` does nothing to outer variables in Main() function. It only modifies `this.message` in reader (so, `reader.message` becomes null). In constructor, it's the `ref` keyword that allows to modify outer variables in the caller, so in my example, only the reader's constructor can do it (and it does - it replaces original instance of OneTimeMessage with SafeMessage).

Comment: Yes I did a unit test and the `Close()` does nothing to outer variable. I am trying to make this work with an actual `Message` type. Your are setting `src` to a `SafeMessage`. The caller will propogate it so I need to make sure it has all the required stuff and ensure they are able to propagate it. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately WCF is very picky and as soon as the Message is touched, it complains about it. Since `SafeMessage` derives from `Message`, I had to implement the abstract stuff and I kept hitting roadblocks after roadblocks especially once I got to `OnWriteBodyContents`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: oh.. I see. That's unfortunate. However, there's still a lot of hope. In the answers of other people (i.e. **IvanStoev**), there are examples of copying messages (`message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue); buffer.CreateMessage();` and so on). Have you tried if it works? I checked MSDN brifly and it seems to be what you need. I'll update in few minutes my answer with an example that uses this approach. I wont be able to test it though

Comment: I posted an answer and took all the suggestions from the answers on this thread including yours. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: oh, I missed that fact. That's great to see you got it solved :) Anyways, since I also worked on that a bit, I added improved example. I actually tested it, and everything works and fails as expected. It's actually quite similar to your version, except for that I included two versions of the Reader there, for a good reason :) Just out of simplicity I dumped whole XML through read-contents, so in fact my naive "ReaderOnce" was .. one-shot only.

Comment: Yes very similar. Good solution. Honestly I learned quite a bit from this project. It was hurdles after hurdles. But good hurdles :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such language construct of course.

What I could suggest is to use `IDisposable` for cleaning up, and add `ref Message message` argument to each `ReadXXX` method. I know it will not be so convenient for your users, but from the other side they cannot forget passing the parameter.

So the implementation would be something like this:

```
internal class MessageReader : IDisposable
{
    private MessageBuffer buffer;
    private Message message;

    private void Release()
    {
        if (buffer == null) return;
        buffer.Close();
        buffer = null;
        message = null;
    }

    protected void OnReadRequest(ref Message message)
    {
        if (message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("message");
        if (this.message == message) return;
        Release();
        this.buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        message = this.message = buffer.CreateMessage();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Release();
    }

    internal string ReadSomething(ref Message message, string id)
    {
        OnReadRequest(ref message);
        // Return string
    }

    internal string ReadSomethingElse(ref Message message, string id)
    {
        OnReadRequest(ref message);
        // Return string
    }
}
```

and the sample usage:

```
using (var reader = new MessageReader())
{
     var a = reader.ReadSomething(ref originalMessage, "something");
     var b = reader.ReadSomethingElse(ref originalMessage, "something");

     // Do something with what was read
}

// At this point originalMessage will be the copy of the message and no longer the original message.
```

Comment: I could have just done this if IDisposable was used: `using (var reader = new MessageReader(ref original)) { ... }`. and set `ref to copy` in `Dispose()`

Comment: The problem is that you can't store `ref Message` inside your reader class (even with upcoming C#7 `ref local/return`feature). Though what you are saying will work if you create the buffer inside the constructor and replace the passed message immediately. The only drawback will be that it will not be lazy, so if no `Read` method is called, it will end up with unnecessary copy.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do this is as follows:

```
public MessageReader: IDisposable
{
     public static MessageReader Create(ref Message message)
     {
         var buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(/*whatever is fit*/);

         try
         {
             var reader = new MessageReader(buffer);
             message = buffer.CreateMessage();
             return reader;
         }
         catch
         {
             buffer.Close();
             throw;
         }
     }

     private readonly MessageBuffer buffer;
     private bool disposed;

     private MessageReader(MessageBuffer buffer) { this.buffer = buffer; }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         if (disposed)
             return;

         buffer.Close();
         disposed = true;
     }

     public string Read(string id)
     {
          var newCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
          //work with new copy...
     }
}
```

And you'd simply use it like this:

```
using (var reader = MessageReader.Create(ref message))
//message here is already an untouched copy with no need of user active
//intervention and is never touched again by the reader.
{
    var a = reader.Read("something"); //reads copy
    ...
}
```

IMHO, this is as clean as it can be. Note that `MessageReader` implements `IDisposable` exclusively because it holds a reference to the disposable private `MessageBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Right now I am trying @quetzalcoatl's suggestion. From a quick look at yours, you are referencing instance members from a static constructor which will not work. Also, not sure what you mean by `buffer.CreateCopy()` because there is no such method.

Comment: @CodingYoshi whoops, two stupid mistakes. `CreateCopy` should be `CreateMessage` and the instance field should have been a local. Coding on a cell phone  is tricky ;). Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the help from @InBetween, @quetzalcoatl, and  @Ivan Stoev. Upvoted your answers because it helped me arrive at the following.

In the constructor, I create a copy of the message and set the original message to the copy. Since the status of this message is `Created` WCF will be happy propogating it. I create another copy and use that for reading multiple times.

@Ivan said but what if the user does not ask for anything to be read then the copying was wasted work. That is a good point but in my case, this is an interceptor and all messages are intercepted to be read.

Here is the code I ended up with suggestions from all of you:

```
public class MessageReader : IDisposable {
   private readonly Message message;

   public MessageReader(ref Message originalMessage) {

      using( var buffer = originalMessage.CreateBufferedCopy( int.MaxValue ) ) {

         // Keep original message for reading 
         this.message = buffer.CreateMessage();

         // Set original message to a copy of the original
         originalMessage = buffer.CreateMessage();
      }
   }

   public int ReadSomething(string id) {

       // Read from this.message;  
   }

   public int ReadSomethingElse(string id) {

       // Read from this.message;    
   }

   public void Close() {
      this.Dispose();
   }

   public void Dispose() {

      this.message.Close();
   }
}
```

The caller can either use it in a using block or without it. The using block is used for good reasons and not as a hack.

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel,
   InstanceContext instanceContext) {
   try {
      using( var rdr = new MessageReader(ref request) ) {

         var value= rdr.ReadSomething( someIdentifier );
         return value;
      }
   }
   catch( System.Exception ex ) {

      throw CreateFault( ex, request );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no language construct in c# that does what you are asking. As stated in comments, you could *abuse* `IDisposable` and the language and use a `using` block to achieve what you want.

But, I fail see what you are gaining, you are just punting the problem; now users will need to remember to use `using`instead of `Close`. The latter is simple and clean, the former uses a very known language construct to do something different to what it was thought for, something that will potentially be very confusing.

Comment: You are absolutely right about IDisposable and I thought about that myself and this is why I wanted to ask to see if there is something out there which I dont know about.